# Protractor: browser.variableName sometimes is undefined and sometimes it has a value

Tags: input, browser, protractor, global-variables

I'm testing nonAngular page with Protractor. I have a variable, which I use across specs stored as browser object. The problem is that I use it in certain spec, but sometimes it get's undefined. Strangely in the same spec file, few cases before it is used without a problem. It seems as if it loses the value in between even though I don't call it or manipulate it.

Conf:

```
onPrepare: function() {
    ...
    beforeAll(function) {
        return browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    }
}
```

Spec 1 in which I define this variable:

```
// page objects
var createUserPage = require('...

// variables
var username = '';

describe(... {
    it(... {
        ...
        // initializing page objects
        var createUser = new createUserPage();

        // store useername text in global variable
        createUser.successfullyCreatedUserText.getText().then(function(text) {
            browser.username = text;
        });
    });
});
```

Spec 2 in which I use this variable:

```
describe(... {
    it(... {
        ...
        // display username
        console.log("Username: " + browser.username);

        // enter username
        home.usernameInput.clear().sendKeys(browser.username);

        // pause browser
        browser.sleep(500);

        // click on Search button
        home.searchButton.click();
    });
});
```

As written before I get console output like:

> Username: undefined

and error in stack trace:

> TypeError: each key must be a number of string; got undefined

This doesn't happen all the time, but rather occasionally. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would declare the variable in your config, either as a `global` or a `param`.  I would probably do it the `global` way, since params are typically assigned in the config before running tests.

```
onPrepare: function() {
    global.username;
}
```

Then in your specs you can assign the value (cant remember if you use `global.username` or just `username` in the specs) and the variable will persist as long as that driver session stays alive.

Comment: Instead of creating a new variable in global scope, it can be created in `params` object of config file and can be accessed using `browser.params.username`

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj Yes, I mentioned that in the answer

Comment: @Gunderson This is exactly what I was looking for, persistent global varable. I set it in onPrepare function as global.username and then called it in specs as global.username as well.

Comment: @Gunderson Bad news, still the same problem, value set in global.username still gets lost occasionally somehow. I used your proposal, so it puzzles me that in few describes before works perfectly and value is still there and in the mean time I don't use, or manipulate it. Any thoughts what else could be wrong? My goal is to have one global variable with persistent value defined in one spec and then used in another.

Comment: @jurijk Hmm I'm not sure, I use the `global` method myself for a few variables.  Declare in the config, assign the value in one spec, and then use that value in another spec... never had this issue.  The only idea I have right now is maybe you are accidentally overwriting it yourself.  These specs are running in the same driver session, right?  Are you sure it is only declared once, and then only defined once?

Comment: @Gunderson Yes, specs are running in one driver session and global variable is only declared and defined once. So no obvious reason why it changes to undefined. I don't delete or define another value to it. What puzzles me at most that it doesn't loose the value sometimes. Like if I run protractor two times (waiting for previous driver session to finish), it passes once, then it looses the value or vice versa.